# how to convert '8/07/2020' to date as 2020-07-08

Tags: google-bigquery

How to convert '8/07/2020' to date as 2020-07-08. I've written the below query:
SELECT PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', '8/07/2020') as Date

It gives me error: Failed to parse input string "8/07/2020"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the slashes. Year and day have been mixed up too.

```sql
SELECT PARSE_DATE('%d/%m/%Y', '8/07/2020') as Date
```